# The best way to manage a Multi-Module Android Library?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

Here is what my library project looks like,

```
|project-lib
|
|--/lib-a
|  |-- build.gradle
|       |-- implementation project(":lib-b")
|       |-- apply plugin: 'maven'
|
|--/lib-b
|  |-- build.gradle
|  |-- apply plugin: 'maven'
|
|-- build.gradle
|--
```

here is my app project:

```
|project-app
|
|--/app
|  |-- build.gradle
|       |-- implementation 'xx.xx:lib-a:1.0.0'
|       |-- implementation 'xx.xx:lib-b:1.0.0'
|
```

And when I try to sync project-app, I got an error

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: xx:lib-b:unspecified
```

how do I sovle this?